# Perforce - How to sync specific file types only in certain folders in P4

Tags: filter, perforce, p4v

We have a P4 repo where we have multiple source and compiled data files alongside each other.
Normally this wouldn't be a problem but I work across multiple teams, so there's certain folders where I need the source files, while in the vast majority of cases I don't (and it's literally terabytes of data).

Is it possible in P4 to setup a filter either on the stream or on the workspace, so that I have something along the line:

```
include root/
exclude *.max
exclude *.ma
exclude *.mb
include root/Engine/Data/Models/Reference/*.max
include root/Engine/Data/Models/Reference/*.ma
include root/Engine/Data/Models/Reference/*.mb
```

ie: exclude all .max and .maya files by default, but include them in the folder and subfolders of the Reference folder (bonus points if this can be done from the P4V UI).


I know there's a way to do this one by one file, but that's not a option since there's several hundred files in there and there's new ones added every few days by artists.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

From a best-practices point of view (in terms of both conceptual simplicity of workspace mappings and performance of the Perforce server), it would be preferable to organize the depot in such a way that the source and compiled files are in separate folders, rather than only being separable by file extension and/or name.  Presumably if the compiled files went into a "generated" folder you could simply map that entire folder as the general rule, add in the specific source folders you need the source for, and call it a day, without needing any tricky overlapping exclude/include logic.

Streams flatly do not allow the level of granularity you're describing; you can "ignore" an extension across the board, and you can include/exclude individual folders, but you can't mix and match those rules as you describe; this is a forcing function for simpler depot structures.  Streams are meant to encourage/enforce best practices, and were built in part as a way to constrain users from building arbitrarily complex client views that have historically been shown to be difficult to support.

In a "classic" client view (i.e. a client where the View is constructed manually rather than being auto-generated based on a stream) you do still have that arbitrary level of flexibility, and can build mappings like:

```
//depot/root/... //my-client/...
-//depot/root/....max //my-client/....max
-//depot/root/....ma //my-client/....ma
-//depot/root/....mb //my-client/....mb
//depot/root/Engine/Data/Models/Reference/*.max //my-client/Engine/Data/Models/Reference/*.max
//depot/root/Engine/Data/Models/Reference/*.ma //my-client/Engine/Data/Models/Reference/*.ma
//depot/root/Engine/Data/Models/Reference/*.mb //my-client/Engine/Data/Models/Reference/*.mb
```

with the caveat that the performance does not scale arbitrarily -- in particular, combining a large number of rules like this with a similar set of rules in the protection table can significantly slow down server operations that need to join the two mappings (which is most of them).